# trying to install cudf but cannot find a version that matches with pd what should be the version of pandas and cudf or where can i find the doc

Tags: pandas, rapids, cudf

```
(base) mitul@pop-os:~$ work
(rapids-24.02) mitul@pop-os:~$ python 
Python 3.10.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Dec 23 2023, 15:36:39) [GCC 12.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cudf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mitul/miniconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    _setup_numba()
  File "/home/mitul/miniconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/utils/_numba.py", line 124, in _setup_numba
    _get_cc_60_ptx_file()
  File "/home/mitul/miniconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/utils/_numba.py", line 16, in _get_cc_60_ptx_file
    from cudf._lib import strings_udf
  File "/home/mitul/miniconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/_lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import (
  File "avro.pyx", line 1, in init cudf._lib.avro
  File "column.pyx", line 23, in init cudf._lib.column
  File "/home/mitul/miniconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/utils/dtypes.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cudf.api.types import is_bool, is_float, is_integer
  File "/home/mitul/miniconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/api/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cudf.api import extensions, types
  File "/home/mitul/miniconda3/envs/rapids-24.02/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/api/types.py", line 503, in <module>
    is_extension_type = pd_types.is_extension_type
AttributeError: module 'pandas.api.types' has no attribute 'is_extension_type'. Did you mean: 'is_extension_array_dtype'?
>>>
```

i tried multiple installations from rapidsai and custom ones too installing each lib one by one
nothing seems to work also tried downgrading numpy and pandas but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

The current release of RAPIDS cuDF 24.02 supports `pandas>=1.3,<1.6.0dev0`. The nightly release of RAPIDS cuDF 24.04 supports `pandas>=2.0,<2.2.2dev0`.

Supported dependency versions for cudf can be read in the `pyproject.toml` file (https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/blob/branch-24.04/python/cudf/pyproject.toml) or by reading the dependencies of the conda packages hosted here (click the info icon next to the desired package): https://anaconda.org/rapidsai/cudf/files

The major version upgrade from pandas 1 to pandas 2 is announced here: https://docs.rapids.ai/notices/rsn0036/

Documentation for the cudf library is hosted at https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/stable/.